# Keras Sequential model gives less accuracy than Functional Model though being same

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I trained two models having same trainable parameters and same structure. But the Functional model performs better compared to Sequential model. Trying to predict a vector from a given image. The image output is from vgg16 model. excludes top layer. When compared the original vector with the predicted vector. Functional model tends to have greater similarity with original vector. Can someone explain why does this happen?

Code below -

```
from keras.models import Sequential
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow import keras
from numpy import random
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

epochs=2000

x = random.random_sample((1, 4096))
y = np.array([ 0.01897711, 0.00196044, -0.0100884 , 0.08048831, 0.07945059, -0.13450155, -0.00228113, 0.30315322, -0.2170798 , 0.12462355, -0.12226178, -0.19237731, -0.14406398, 0.11556922, 0.04466464, -0.22505943, -0.07492258, -0.05925079, 0.02871693, -0.32403016, 0.16885516, -0.01677704, 0.03490563, 0.08720589, -0.03105724, -0.10850648, 0.04820024, -0.1348836 , -0.26358405, 0.08388387, 0.13177398, 0.00133367, -0.01074621, -0.01703981, 0.14912938, 0.13562258, 0.12910905, -0.02097122, -0.05823291, -0.21523051, -0.1051832 , -0.0112495 , -0.02306462, 0.30883443, 0.24211378, -0.01332151, -0.04171557, -0.07624041, 0.05742156, 0.17561561, -0.05971769, -0.22914584, -0.2354534 , -0.12413627, -0.02892042, -0.08661073, 0.14135012, -0.15514424, -0.09965582, -0.13770337, 0.09548005, 0.0925705 , -0.10030732, 0.16057852, -0.17537649, 0.23076315, -0.12471516, 0.2811343 , -0.1576465 , 0.17364068, 0.0658261 , 0.044597 , 0.27390295, -0.04520088, 0.00317772, 0.05926268, 0.06897669, -0.2579084 , -0.30417407, -0.08170868, -0.10205928, -0.14339833, -0.2291172 , 0.1584655 , -0.108877 , 0.03841971, -0.02097263, -0.00477816, -0.08784705, 0.00944081, 0.01409219, 0.1655657 , 0.09393094, 0.233216 , 0.28611556, -0.00573498, 0.1374636 , -0.19641444, 0.14472656, 0.254758 , -0.26166946, 0.30998066, 0.1026804 , -0.0578127 , -0.0882837 , -0.25514072, 0.12337176, 0.1786545 , 0.04052542, -0.17535737, -0.05401937, -0.27649277, -0.04952267, 0.08122452, 0.04374097, -0.07044917, 0.0653659 , -0.36983526, -0.02356564, -0.01144519, 0.1440273 , 0.12321867, 0.10163002, -0.13444787, -0.06148207, 0.11309719, -0.24679276, -0.04028287, -0.0930292 , -0.06392674, 0.10477038, 0.00828285, -0.11968364, -0.16145884, -0.08808196, 0.14231506, -0.02768413, -0.24046096, 0.02477906, -0.3868386 , 0.08224358, -0.30728677, -0.31634584, -0.24805053, -0.19289431, -0.04890246, -0.23479757, 0.13149938, 0.02801071, 0.12761658, 0.02897108, -0.14499697, 0.05322106, 0.06153642, -0.21517622, 0.255269 , 0.08573797, 0.09940388, -0.10590497, 0.13063994, 0.11253715, 0.15636472, -0.19782121, 0.01258014, -0.04391019, 0.16168897, -0.05669969, -0.17957021, -0.04841055, -0.00175814, -0.25425357, 0.14485207, 0.08319512, -0.20990393, 0.04344559, 0.20995931, -0.16608813, 0.28736553, 0.12240092, 0.12146739, 0.05718496, 0.01994314, 0.09686041, 0.13452487, 0.1052431 , 0.10266875, -0.01051683, 0.01536175, 0.25623122, 0.11273847, 0.06577922, -0.09992851, -0.02046986, -0.11516961, 0.12051879, 0.00518495, 0.0988002 , -0.279763 , -0.09997523, -0.04474135])
y = y.reshape(1,-1)

inputs  = Input(shape=(4096,))
decoder = Dense(256, activation="sigmoid")(inputs)
decoder = Dense(256, activation="sigmoid")(decoder)
decoder = Dense(256, activation="sigmoid")(decoder)
outputs = Dense(200, activation="sigmoid")(decoder)

functional = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
functional.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=opt)

sequen = Sequential()
sequen.add(Dense(256,input_shape=(4096,),activation="sigmoid"))
sequen.add(Dense(256,activation="sigmoid"))
sequen.add(Dense(256,activation="sigmoid"))
sequen.add(Dense(200,activation="sigmoid"))
sequen.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=opt)

functional.fit(x,y,verbose=1,validation_data=(x, y),epochs=epochs)
sequen.fit(x,y,verbose=1,validation_data=(x, y),epochs=epochs)


functional_output = cosine_similarity(functional.predict(x),y)
sequential_output = cosine_similarity(sequen.predict(x),y)
print(functional_output,sequential_output)

#Calculating cosine_similarity between both outputs. Functional api gives gives better output.
#output - array([[0.65056009]]), array([[0.19631703]])
```

**Functional Model Structure**

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)        [(None, 4096)]            0         
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 256)               1048832   
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 256)               65792     
                                                                 
 dense_2 (Dense)             (None, 256)               65792     
                                                                 
 dense_3 (Dense)             (None, 200)               51400     
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 1,231,816
Trainable params: 1,231,816
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

[image: Functional Model Structure]

**Sequential Model Structure**

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 dense_4 (Dense)             (None, 256)               1048832   
                                                                 
 dense_5 (Dense)             (None, 256)               65792     
                                                                 
 dense_6 (Dense)             (None, 256)               65792     
                                                                 
 dense_7 (Dense)             (None, 200)               51400     
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 1,231,816
Trainable params: 1,231,816
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

[image: Sequential Model Structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two models are initialized with different weights and biases. You can initialize the weights and biases of the model as a zeros matrix by adding the parameters, `kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Zeros()` and `bias_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Zeros()`. And if you run this code, you will see similar results, but not identical.
As pointed out by [@AloneTogether](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9657861/alonetogether), after training your first model, the optimizer already has an internal state. So, initializing that optimizer again would fix this issue.

So, if you run this code, you will get identical results:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow as tf
from numpy import random
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

epochs=200

x = random.random_sample((1, 4096))
y = np.array([ 0.01897711, 0.00196044, -0.0100884 , 0.08048831, 0.07945059, -0.13450155, -0.00228113, 0.30315322, -0.2170798 , 0.12462355, -0.12226178, -0.19237731, -0.14406398, 0.11556922, 0.04466464, -0.22505943, -0.07492258, -0.05925079, 0.02871693, -0.32403016, 0.16885516, -0.01677704, 0.03490563, 0.08720589, -0.03105724, -0.10850648, 0.04820024, -0.1348836 , -0.26358405, 0.08388387, 0.13177398, 0.00133367, -0.01074621, -0.01703981, 0.14912938, 0.13562258, 0.12910905, -0.02097122, -0.05823291, -0.21523051, -0.1051832 , -0.0112495 , -0.02306462, 0.30883443, 0.24211378, -0.01332151, -0.04171557, -0.07624041, 0.05742156, 0.17561561, -0.05971769, -0.22914584, -0.2354534 , -0.12413627, -0.02892042, -0.08661073, 0.14135012, -0.15514424, -0.09965582, -0.13770337, 0.09548005, 0.0925705 , -0.10030732, 0.16057852, -0.17537649, 0.23076315, -0.12471516, 0.2811343 , -0.1576465 , 0.17364068, 0.0658261 , 0.044597 , 0.27390295, -0.04520088, 0.00317772, 0.05926268, 0.06897669, -0.2579084 , -0.30417407, -0.08170868, -0.10205928, -0.14339833, -0.2291172 , 0.1584655 , -0.108877 , 0.03841971, -0.02097263, -0.00477816, -0.08784705, 0.00944081, 0.01409219, 0.1655657 , 0.09393094, 0.233216 , 0.28611556, -0.00573498, 0.1374636 , -0.19641444, 0.14472656, 0.254758 , -0.26166946, 0.30998066, 0.1026804 , -0.0578127 , -0.0882837 , -0.25514072, 0.12337176, 0.1786545 , 0.04052542, -0.17535737, -0.05401937, -0.27649277, -0.04952267, 0.08122452, 0.04374097, -0.07044917, 0.0653659 , -0.36983526, -0.02356564, -0.01144519, 0.1440273 , 0.12321867, 0.10163002, -0.13444787, -0.06148207, 0.11309719, -0.24679276, -0.04028287, -0.0930292 , -0.06392674, 0.10477038, 0.00828285, -0.11968364, -0.16145884, -0.08808196, 0.14231506, -0.02768413, -0.24046096, 0.02477906, -0.3868386 , 0.08224358, -0.30728677, -0.31634584, -0.24805053, -0.19289431, -0.04890246, -0.23479757, 0.13149938, 0.02801071, 0.12761658, 0.02897108, -0.14499697, 0.05322106, 0.06153642, -0.21517622, 0.255269 , 0.08573797, 0.09940388, -0.10590497, 0.13063994, 0.11253715, 0.15636472, -0.19782121, 0.01258014, -0.04391019, 0.16168897, -0.05669969, -0.17957021, -0.04841055, -0.00175814, -0.25425357, 0.14485207, 0.08319512, -0.20990393, 0.04344559, 0.20995931, -0.16608813, 0.28736553, 0.12240092, 0.12146739, 0.05718496, 0.01994314, 0.09686041, 0.13452487, 0.1052431 , 0.10266875, -0.01051683, 0.01536175, 0.25623122, 0.11273847, 0.06577922, -0.09992851, -0.02046986, -0.11516961, 0.12051879, 0.00518495, 0.0988002 , -0.279763 , -0.09997523, -0.04474135])
y = y.reshape(1,-1)

inputs  = Input(shape=(4096,))
decoder = Dense(256, activation="sigmoid", kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Zeros(), bias_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Zeros())(inputs)
decoder = Dense(256, activation="sigmoid", kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Zeros(), bias_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Zeros())(decoder)
decoder = Dense(256, activation="sigmoid", kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Zeros(), bias_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Zeros())(decoder)
outputs = Dense(200, activation="sigmoid", kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Zeros(), bias_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Zeros())(decoder)

functional = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
functional.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=opt)

sequen = Sequential()
sequen.add(Input(shape=(4096,)))
sequen.add(Dense(256,activation="sigmoid", kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Zeros(), bias_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Zeros()))
sequen.add(Dense(256,activation="sigmoid", kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Zeros(), bias_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Zeros()))
sequen.add(Dense(256,activation="sigmoid", kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Zeros(), bias_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Zeros()))
sequen.add(Dense(200,activation="sigmoid", kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Zeros(), bias_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Zeros()))

opt2 = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
sequen.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=opt2)

functional.fit(x,y,verbose=1,validation_data=(x, y),epochs=epochs)
sequen.fit(x,y,verbose=1,validation_data=(x, y),epochs=epochs)


functional_output = cosine_similarity(functional.predict(x),y)
sequential_output = cosine_similarity(sequen.predict(x),y)
print(functional_output,sequential_output)
```

Comment: These are the default initializers in Keras ([docs](https://keras.io/api/layers/initializers/)), so it is not clear why your code is expected to produce qualitatively different results than the OP's. The *"similar but not identical*" is key, but again, it does not address OP's claim that the Functional model seems to have better performance.

Answer (score 2):

I think the main problem is that you use the same optimizer to train your models, and after training your first model, the optimizer already has an internal state. Using two separate optimizers seems to yield (almost) identical results:

```
...
opt1 = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
opt2 = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
...
```

```
...
[[0.65034289]] [[0.65033581]]
```

Comment: I ran this code, still results are similar, but not identical.

Comment: Ye. Consider the stochastic nature of both models. Identical results are unrealistic, but I would assume that `output - array([[0.65056009]]), array([[0.19631703]])` is outside the acceptable tolerance.

Comment: It worked when I initialized the weights and biases as zeros matrices. I have updated my answer, thank you!

Comment: Hmm. I do not think that is necessary but yeah..

Comment: I thought the same too, If we initialize the weights as random values, both models show the same results only after a few thousand epochs. But if we initialize the weights as zeros matrices, both models show the same result on every epoch.

Comment: IMO, similar results within a certain tolerance are completely normal. There is no need to change the default parameters.